# Java Socket: data is not transfered

Tags: java, sockets, remote-server

I am new to the socket programming. I'd like to read data from local files and send it to the server by the socket. When testing with same machine(client and server are in one computer), it works. But if I test the server in the remote machine, I did not get the data which I should get from the client machine. Any one can help me to look at my code?Thanks a lot!

```
public class GreetingClient{
private Socket socket;

public GreetingClient(String serverName, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    this(new Socket(serverName,port));
}


public GreetingClient(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hostname;
    int port;
    if (args.length == 2) {
        hostname = args[0];
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    } else {
        hostname = "localhost";
        port = 6066;
    }
    System.out.println("Connecting to " + hostname + " on port " + port);
    String filePath ="C:/Users/Documents/file.xml";
    GreetingClient c;
    try {
        c = new GreetingClient(hostname, port);
        c.send(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void send(String filePath) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream , this.socket.getOutputStream());
    this.socket.getOutputStream().flush();
    this.socket.shutdownOutput();
    System.out.println("Finish sending file to Server.");
}
}




public class GreetingServer extends Thread {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
}
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            if (!server.isClosed()) {
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\n Goodbye!");
            }
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            if (in != null) {
                Upload upload = parseXmlToJaxb(in);
                long clientID = upload.getClientID();
                System.out.println("Client "+clientID);


                server.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unknown Message Received at " + _dateTimeFormatter.format(new Date()));
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I did not get the data which I should*. - In what way?  The wrong data?  No data?  Corrupt data?

Comment: I would strip out lots of code until your just left with a client and server, where the client just sends a simple byte to the server, and see if that works.  Then slowly re-add the other code.

Answer (score 0):

In your send method you're not reading any data from the InputStream. When you call this `new FileInputStream(filePath)` in its constructor just a new File() with target path is created. To get some data, you need to read it from InputStream and after that you may write it to the OutputStream.

So, I think you need to fix your send method.